# Are there limitations to limit to the three.js userData property?

Tags: three.js

I am using the Three.js Object3D userData property to store information from a MySQL database serialized into json pairs to give me data to perform various actions when selecting objects which represent saved data. It seems to work nicely for a few pairs.

I note from the reference a warning to not to store references to functions as they will not be cloned. Can anyone tell me if there any other limitations to this property (number of pairs, hierarchical data, etc.)? I want to store 2-3000 words of text, images, blobs etc., but prefer to ask over trial and error. the documents are a little sparse on such matters.

Many thanks... James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there are not special limitations. It is simply a Javascript object:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/0fbc8afb348198e4924d9805d1d4be5869264418/src/core/Object3D.js#L85

```
this.userData = {};
```

So while your object is in memory, you can put any Javascript variables there. Only limitations are what you always have, the available memory basically. As Javascript objects can contain any types and hierarchy so you're off fine there.

I used this search to check this in the codebase: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=userdata

Comment: Thanks @antont learning by trial and error is a great way to understand a lot of code, but make a single poor implementation decision, and it can mean 100s of hours of work later to undo. Your simple answer is much appreciated as I have a long way to go as I learn JavaScript and Three.js...

Comment: When I store references to other objects, sometimes I get: [Error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. `stringify` (three.js:5521) probably because of circular references.

Comment: @fferri yep that sounds like a circular reference, not a limit otherwise.